# SpringBoot - AOT Compilation - BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor - How does that work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, graalvm

I'm trying to develop my own library for automatic json validation: https://github.com/ugoevola/json-auto-validation

I would like this library to be compatible with AOT.

In this library, I need to generate Bean and Json files. The aim is to generate these resources during compilation when using AOT compilation.

If I understand this sentence correctly, "During Spring AOT processing, your application is started until the bean definitions are available. Bean instances are not created during the AOT processing phase" taken from the Spring documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.developing-your-first-application.buildpacks).
Both, postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry and postProcessBeanFactory will be executed during compilation.

To verify this, I try to generate all my resources using these two methods:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalTime
@Configuration
open class JsonValidationInitialisation : BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {
    companion object : KLogging()

    override fun postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory: ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) {}

    override fun postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(registry: BeanDefinitionRegistry) {
        JsonValidationSchemaGenerator.getInstance().generateJsonSchemaFiles()
        JsonValidationBeanGenerator.getInstance().generateBeans(registry)
    }
}
```

After integrating my library into an API project, there's the build.gradle.kts :

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg") version "1.8.21"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.8.22"
    id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.9.27"
}

...

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
...
    // validation
    implementation("io.github.ugoevola:json-auto-validation:$jsonAutoValidationVersion")
}

kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        val main by getting {
            noArg {
                annotation("some.package.NoArg")
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```

The compilation went well, all file generation methods have been executed, and the files, Beans definitions, Json files, have been generated, but when I launch the API I got this error :

```
2023-09-25T20:26:22.056Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException-->org.uevola.jsonautovalidation.configuration.JsonValidationInitialisation$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerFactoryData.<init>(Enhancer.java:501) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.wrapCachedClass(Enhancer.java:801) ~[na:na]
```

I don't think I understand how the BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor works with AOT compilation...

Could someone please explain?

Comment: Maybe a [BeanRegistrationAotProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current//javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/aot/BeanRegistrationAotProcessor.html) is needed?  There's an example of one [here](https://github.com/marcusdacoregio/spring-native/blob/security-method/samples/security-method/src/main/java/com/example/methodsecurity/PrePostSecuredBeanRegistrationAotProcessor.java).  I've never worked with Spring AOT myself but remember seeing this - could be totally wrong but thought I'd mention it in case it helps.

Comment: Mmm, interesting.
I'll check it out tomorrow.